# How I can play with EC2 API tools?

Tags: java, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm getting the error to run the script "ec2-describe-regions"

```
$ec2-describe-regions
/usr/local/ec2/ec2-api-tools-1.6.14.1/bin/ec2-cmd: line 62: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
```

Before it, I did followings:

1. Open a terminal on my personal computer.
2. Install Java.
3. Create security credentials (an X.509 certificate and private key).
4. Set up a few environment variables.
5. Run my first command.

Here is the information I did:

```
$which java
/usr/bin/java

$echo $EC2_HOME
/usr/local/ec2/ec2-api-tools-1.6.14.1
$echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
$java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: JAVA_HOME doesnt need the /bin/java

Comment: Follow what @Julio has mentioned. The new AWS-CLI is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
mv /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/java.orig
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```

You may have two or more java instances on your server. Make sure you use the same java executable where your `JAVA_HOME` points to.

Answer (score 0):

This command uses the old CLI tools, i'd recommend you use the new, unified and greatly improved CLI:
https://aws.amazon.com/cli/